# Will saved (archive) .PST files open, offline, in versions of Office Outlook pre-2019, after Google/Chrome’s May 30th notice?

Tags: google-chrome, email, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2016

Will saved (archive) .pst files, stored on my internal drives, open offline, in Outlook versions prior to 2019 for searches and read-only, after Google/Chrome’s May 30th notice (copied in below)?

I have some very large archive PST files (over 3GB) that I would prefer to keep on my older PC and laptop, using pre-2019 versions of Outlook. Obviously, as Google advises, I won't be able to use gmail on the older machine or the more-recent laptop, after May 30th, but I need to be able to consult the archive PST files from time to time.

In line with Google's advice I’ve now acquired a WIN11 PC and Office 365, so expect to be able to continue to see my active gmail account in Outlook - it's just the archived .PST files that may be problematic.

Advice, please.

*“On 30 May, you may lose access to apps that are using less secure sign-in technology To help keep your account secure, Google will no longer support the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password. Instead, you’ll need to sign in using Sign in with Google or other more secure technologies, like OAuth 2.0.
Learn more What do you need to do?
Email software, like Outlook 2016 or earlier, has less secure access to your Gmail. Switch to Office 365, Outlook 2019 or newer, or any other email software where you can sign in using Sign in with Google.”*

Comment: This should work. I have archive PST file from various versions of Outlook from 2002 to 365 and they all work. I do not use Google mail with Outlook, but once in Outlook you should be fine.

Comment: Many thanks, John - most helpful (as always). Paul

Comment: Emails saved to a .PST are already offline today.

Comment: @Ramhound On my new machine the Outlook files are .ost files, but on my old machine, the live email file in the My Documents\Outlook file folder is actually Outlook.pst.

Comment: @iSeeker - That sounds like you are downloading the emails off the server using POP3.  Even if you were using IMAP Outlook would be using.OST since both Exchange and IMAP keep emails on the server and only a cache of your emails is kept locally.

Comment: @John Do I understand correctly that the easiest way to open pre-2019 Office Outlook offline (as will be necessary from May 30th 2022) will be to set it offline before closing it on May 29th?  (I’ve seen online discussions claiming that one can’t get into offline without first opening online, which shouldn’t work from May 30th.) However, I’ve just tried closing Outlook in offline mode and then when I reopened it, was still in offline mode. So this should work?

Comment: You can open a PST file when Outlook is online. I do that routinely. You need to be online to recover with an OST file.

Comment: Yes, currently; but my Outlook acts as a front end to Gmail, and come May 30th, I fear it won't open online, as per Google's warning to upgrade to Office 2019 or MS 365. Or have I completely misunderstood their warning? (Thanks for sticking with the thread.)

Comment: @iSeeker There appears to be a misunderstanding of what a `.pst` is and unless using POP3, non-exchange accounts use an `.ost`. A `.pst` houses asynchronous data, whereas an `.ost` is always synchronous since it's only a cache of what's on the server and is incapable of being out of sync with the server _(delete an `.ost` and no data is lost since it rebuilds on the next sync)_. Unless POP3, any emails from Gmail copied to an archive `.pst` no longer require authentication to access and are therefore unaffected by Google disabling the ability to use app passwords in Outlook.

Comment: @iSeeker _(Cont'd)_ I can't recall if versions of Outlook a decade ago used a `.pst` for Gmail _(Hotmail did up until ~2010ish)_, but if so, verify whether you can access the emails in the `.pst` without authenticating, and if not, authenticate, then copy all data in it to a new `.pst` _(Copy to folder...)_

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for that. Searching my two PCs (including for hidden files) shows .OST files in the right folder on my new Win11 PC. However, my old WIN7 PC, from which I’m just now migrating, shows only .PST files (the ones operating my two current live gmail accounts as well as archived and historic .PSTs, plus a couple of old copied .OSTs related to prior employment with Date Modified still at 2014). While I don’t fully understand POP/IMAP when accessing Gmail from other clients, my gmail settings show “POP  enabled… since 10/02/2010… IMAP is enabled.” It seems I’m using both POP and IMAP.

Comment: @JW0914 (Cont'd) While I don’t fully understand POP/IMAP when accessing Gmail from other clients, my gmail settings show “POP  enabled… since 10/02/2010… IMAP is enabled.” It seems I’m using both POP and IMAP. Some of my old PSTs are named as Archive, but I think I created them by just exporting folders as .PST data files, not by declaring them formally as Archived. However, in the current migration process I’ve copied all the old .PSTs to an external drive, which I’ll keep as a backup; so I should be covered for the risk in your continuation comment. Again thanks.

Comment: @iSeeker On the client side, either POP3 or IMAP is used _(server can enable both, but the client dictates which protocol is used to pull the mail)_. Just for clarity, for the old Gmail `.pst`'s, ensure you can access the data within them without authenticating to Gmail _(disconnect PC from internet and test open multiple emails)_, as simply copying the `.pst` themselves won't fix that if accessing those `.pst`'s require authentication to access their data _(e.g. if the latter is the case, a new `.pst` would need to be created and all data copied from the old `.pst` to the new `.pst`)_

Comment: _(POP3 is feature limited and if you accessed the same account side by side with POP3 and IMAP, you'd immediately know which was POP3 from the folder hierarchy alone)_

Comment: @JW0914 It works! Turned off internet, opened Outlook 2010 (which went straight to Offline mode) and I was able to open all the .PST files. The ones for my current accounts (as distinct from archived/saved .PSTs) were populated up to the day I last had Outlook online - three days ago, while Gmail had been up-to-date till I turned off  the internet connection. So it looks like everything will work as desired, come May 30th.

Answer (score -1):

Agree with John, it should work. For the announcement of Gmail, I think it is aimed at the restriction of logging in to Gmail account on an older version than Outlook 2019. The archived email is not associated with Gmail account, which does not require account password login, so it should be able to be opened normally.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it's a comment

Comment: Good to an explanation for a downvote (assuming both from are from the same source). I wish they'd do that more in StkEx-Physics and Maths